# Are Azure Functions compiled into native with .NET Core?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have durable orchestration and azure functions implemented in .NET Core 2.2, currently supported for Azure functions v2. My company is building performance critical operations. I would like to know more if the published project is compiled in the production into native compilation of .NET Core 2.2. Eventually how could I setup native compilation in the deployment configuration?

Comment: What makes you think native compilation is going to help your performance when you're already beholden to the internet latency?

Comment: @DaviG The use case is to process hunderds thousands or millions of records in SaaS. The internet latency occurs during the request e.g. upload data, but the most expensive time is processing them where I utilize some mathematical algorithms. Some references I have attached already as native DLL written in C/C++.

Comment: @DavidG Even if latency was an issue in his case, latency is in addition to computational speed, a reduction of time in either stage is still a reduction. Its the same scenario with loading web pages, the time it takes to compute logic should still be reduced.

Comment: @KieranDevlin Yes, but if the reduction is 1ms when the internet latency is 1000ms, does it really matter? My point is the optimisation like this may not be particularly useful, see [here](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) for example

Comment: @DavidG data processing of millions records in cloud services is not about milliseconds but different time scale. Also page loading speed up in milliseconds matters, therefore internet continuously is changing protocols HTTP 1.1, 2.0 and now coming HTTP /3 (QUIC). The impact is huge because savings milliseconds per page is saving many lives as total sum of time reductions.

Comment: Just as an additional information. The native compilation should be significantly faster. In my test native DLL lib written in C could executed the same operation 6x time faster than in .NET. Sure, this is also a reason why has been native compilation developed by Microsoft.